# Dell precision 5510 - unplugging power cable while in sleep mode causes unexpected shutdown

Tags: laptop, battery, sleep, shutdown, dell-xps

When the power cable is connected and the computer is put in sleep mode it wakes up fine. If I unplug the cable after the computer was put in sleep mode, or if I put it to sleep mode after I have unplugged it, it will shutdown unexpectedly and start fresh.

Computer works fine when I unplug it when it's on. The only problem seems to be the combination of sleep mode and being unplugged (for now).

QUESTION: should I suspect battery issues at this point? My guess is the battery does not keep voltage high enough when the power cable is off.

Adding some screenshots showing when this started to happen after:
[image]

ADDENDUM: windows 10 battery report: https://pastebin.com/raw/Rz1ehZBm

Comment: The next diagnostic step I would take (and post here) would be to get the battery information from the system.  https://www.wikihow.com/Run-an-Energy-Report-on-Windows-7  for Windows 7 or https://www.windowscentral.com/generate-battery-report-windows-10 for Windows 10 (ie run powercfg) and this can tell you the state of battery health.

Comment: Great suggestion. Here it is (will add to the OP as well): https://pastebin.com/raw/Rz1ehZBm

Comment: This does not look like a battery hardwae issue to me. I did just see that a new Firmware update has jst come out (12 August 2019) for that device - If the problem is new, you may want to see if its related. If its old you may want to try flashing your BIOS. I found the information at https://www.dell.com/support/home/nz/en/nzdhs1/product-support/product/precision-m5510-workstation/drivers

Comment: The problem was happening when I just got the machine (its a used one) about 8 months ago. Then it suddenly stopped, not reappeared and is very consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, maybe one of the battery cells is dead. One cell could cause what you're experiencing. The voltage does come up, but since a cell is dead the capacity is diminished.
Another example of this would be, you unplug it, and start a program, that will cause the CPU to spike, probably the hard drive to spin up and the power draw too much for the battery soon after the BMS (battery management system) reports low voltage, computer believes battery is low and turns itself off, or dies before shutdown.

You could just try to discard windows or some other program playing tricks by going into the BIOS and unplugging it, if it dies immediately... you'll know it's probably hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - not sure i understood the last suggestion though. My computer does not die if I unplug it, I would doubt that it will die in BIOS as well. I have not tried to the suggestion with CPU spike, I think I will be able to just load the CPU with special utilities that exit.

Comment: From the error I grasped that the machine was randomly turning off, since it said it didn't turn off cleanly. Hmm my guess if it's just during suspend is either driver issue, or BSOD during wake up.
The reason I say this is because this seems to happen during S state changes.

Have you contacted their support? there might be a recall or there might be a driver update. Another option you could try is disabling also C-states if possible in the bios and checking if the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling hybrid sleep in the advanced power settings for both "battery" and "plugged in" settings.

This fixed this specific issue for me.